# Oracke ADF 12c: Refresh Table within a popup after entering filtering criteria

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

Hello we are using oracle ADF 12c. We have some popups with tables blocks and at the top of each table column, there is data filter/search box. Whenever a data is entered in the filter box and "Enter" is pressed the popup gets closed automatically. Next time the popup is opened, the filtered data appears

The problem which I see is that by pressing "Enter", automatically "OK" button is clicked. How can we prevent this to happen and let the popup just refresh the table block only when "Enter" is pressed.

This works very well if the table block is not in a popup, by pressing enter, the blocks gets refreshed and data is appeared but doesn't work in popup and we need to filter data in table blocks of popups also.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the popup property autoCancel is set to false. Then I can only assume you use an af:dialog of type OK or OKCANCEL. You can use the type NONE and handle the OK and CANCEL button yourself, just as any other regular button.

Add actionListeners to the buttons, and inside the listeners, you close the popup.